# t-sql Order Union statement Alphabetically with subgroups

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm really hoping I'm just having a major brain freeze. I have a query with 3 unions.  Query 1 retrieves a school, Query 2 retrieves Academies within the school, Query 3 retrieves pathways within each academy.  I want the final sorted product to look like this:

School
  Academy A
    Pathway 1
    Pathway 2
  Academy B
    Pathway 1
  Academy C
    Pathway 1
    Pathway 2
    Pathway 3

My query below does this; however I want the Academies alphabetized and that is where I'm struggling.  Am I overlooking something obvious?

Here's my query:

```
Declare @schoolID int = 76

Select  l.schoolID      schoolID,
        null            academyID,
        null            pathwayID,
        l.locationName  targetName, 
        cast((1 - sum(ttlDaysMissed) / sum(ttlSchoolDays)) * 100 as decimal(5,1)) pct,
        1               srt1
From    cacheAttendanceAOLStudents aas
        Join dimLocation l on l.schoolID = aas.schoolID 
Where   aas.schoolID = @schoolID
Group by l.schoolID, l.locationName

UNION 
Select  aas.schoolID,
        a.aolAcademyID,
        null,
        a.academyName,
        cast((1 - sum(ttlDaysMissed) / sum(ttlSchoolDays)) * 100 as decimal(5,1)) pct,
        2
From    cacheAttendanceAOLStudents aas
        Join aolPathwayLocations pl on pl.aolPathwayLocationID = aas.aolPathwayLocationID
        Join aolAcademies a on a.aolAcademyID = pl.aolAcademyID
Where   aas.schoolID = @schoolID
Group by aas.schoolID, a.aolAcademyID, a.academyName

UNION 

Select  aas.schoolID,
        pl.aolAcademyID,
        pl.aolPathwayID,
        p.academyPathway,
        cast((1 - sum(ttlDaysMissed) / sum(ttlSchoolDays)) * 100 as decimal(5,1)) pct,
        2
From    cacheAttendanceAOLStudents aas
        Join aolPathwayLocations pl on pl.aolPathwayLocationID = as.aolPathwayLocationID
        Join aolPathways p on p.aolPathwayID = pl.aolPathwayID
Where   aas.schoolID = @schoolID
Group by aas.schoolID, pl.aolAcademyID, pl.aolPathwayID, p.academyPathway
order by srt1
```

And here's a query to run to give the results:

```
Select 76 schoolID, null academyID, null pathwayID, 'Doss High' targetName, 91.2 pct, 1 srt1
UNION 
Select 76, 24, null, 'Academy Not Identified', 90.6, 2
UNION 
Select 76, 11, null, 'Freshman Academy', 93.4, 2
UNION 
Select 76, 24, 55, 'Pathway Not Identified', 90.6, 2
UNION 
Select 76, 11, 55, 'Pathway Not Identified', 93.4, 2
order by srt1
```

And here's what the finished result set looks like...if the 'targetNames' were in correct alphabetical order it would be perfect...

```
schoolID    academyID   pathwayID   targetName              pct    srt1
76          NULL        NULL        Doss High               91.2    1
76          11          NULL        Freshman Academy        93.4    2
76          11          55          Pathway Not Identified  93.4    2
76          24          NULL        Academy Not Identified  90.6    2
76          24          55          Pathway Not Identified  90.6    2
```

Comment: `order by srt1, targetName`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `ORDER BY targetname` not `srt1`

```
Select 76 schoolID, null academyID, null pathwayID, 'Doss High' targetName, 91.2 pct, 1 srt1
UNION 
Select 76, 24, null, 'Academy Not Identified', 90.6, 2
UNION 
Select 76, 11, null, 'Freshman Academy', 93.4, 2
UNION 
Select 76, 24, 55, 'Pathway Not Identified', 90.6, 2
UNION 
Select 76, 11, 55, 'Pathway Not Identified', 93.4, 2
order by targetName;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the union will order by all the unioned result sets.

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/6274)

The 'targetNames' will be in the correct alphabetical order:

```
| schoolID | academyID | pathwayID |             targetName |  pct | srt1 |
|----------|-----------|-----------|------------------------|------|------|
|       76 |        24 |    (null) | Academy Not Identified | 90.6 |    2 |
|       76 |    (null) |    (null) |              Doss High | 91.2 |    1 |
|       76 |        11 |    (null) |       Freshman Academy | 93.4 |    2 |
|       76 |        11 |        55 | Pathway Not Identified | 93.4 |    2 |
|       76 |        24 |        55 | Pathway Not Identified | 90.6 |    2 |
```

Comment: I'm sorry I see some of my initial post got "squished" together.  I want the name of the school to be on the first line (the one with no academy or pathway ID).  Then, I want the Academies listed in alphabetical order (the ones with no pathway ID)...BUT, in between each Academy I want the pathways associated with that academy listed (i.e. 'Doss High', 'Academy Not Identified', 'Pathway Not Identified', 'Freshman Academy', 'Pathway Not Identified').  So adding the sort field gives me the school name first, but then I don't know how to intermingle/order Academies & Pathways...